# Trouble Printing Selected Images in Ionic 7 - iOS Native Print Dialog Issue

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, plugins, cross-platform, ionic7

I'm encountering difficulties printing images that have been scanned or chosen from the gallery in an Ionic 7 application. Despite successfully implementing image scanning and selection functionalities, I'm facing an issue where only the screenshot of the current viewport is being printed instead of the selected images when attempting to use the native iOS print dialog.

I've tried utilizing web print solutions and experimented with the Cordova print plugin, but none have provided the desired outcome. I'm seeking guidance or solutions on how to effectively print the specifically selected images within the Ionic 7 app through the native iOS print dialog. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to enable successful printing of these images would be greatly appreciated.

My primary objective is to resolve this issue and enable the functionality to directly print the selected images through the native iOS print dialog. I seek guidance, suggestions, or a potential workaround to ensure that the images selected or scanned by users are accurately transmitted for printing, bypassing the current challenge of printing only the viewport screenshot.

Specifically, I'm interested in any insights, code examples, or recommended plugins/APIs that could effectively address this problem. I'm open to alternative approaches or best practices within the Ionic framework that might facilitate a seamless integration with the native iOS print dialog, ensuring the accurate printing of the selected images.